# Pandas: Organising a large col numbered DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` that looks something like this:

```
         ID         x1_2020-04-07  x2_2020-04-07  x1_2020-04-08   x2_2020-04-08
0     102717           21.0             11              15              21
1     136703           12.0             15              88              27
2     105140            2.0             39              53              24
```

Essentially, `x1` and `x2` are variables I am tracking over a date range: `2020-04-07 to 2020-04-08`

But I would like to somehow organise this df so it can be queried easier, I am possibly looking to introduce a MultiIndex maybe which takes `x1` and `x2` to an upper level and then dates below like this:

```
MultiIndex              x1              x2              x1              x2
         ID         2020-04-07      2020-04-07      2020-04-08       2020-04-08
0     102717           21.0             11              15              21
1     136703           12.0             15              88              27
2     105140            2.0             39              53              24
```

The goal is to be able to look at deviations in `x1` and/or `x2` over time so I am trying to be efficient in how this `df` is structured.

How would I go about creating a `df` like this?

*EDIT*

or like this:

```
MultiIndex           2020-04-07      2020-04-07      2020-04-08       2020-04-08
         ID             x1              x2              x1              x2
0     102717           21.0             11              15              21
1     136703           12.0             15              88              27
2     105140            2.0             39              53              24
```

Comment: Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, so how would I handle this if a col name was `x1_v1_2020-04-07`

Comment: then use `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)` ?

Comment: Ahh thank you. WIll read up on this part of documentation - ahh I think my issue is some cols might be `1_2_3_2020-04-01` and some might be `1_2_2020-04-02`

Comment: So I just renamed the cols to make my life easier - How would I swap them so dates is the index not `x1` and `x2` ?

Comment: I think best is edit question, because seems it is more complicated. So reopened question

Comment: @jezrael. Ok have edited Q :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) for change order of levels of splitted columns names to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
print (df)

       2020-04-07     2020-04-08    
               x1  x2         x1  x2
ID                                  
102717       21.0  11         15  21
136703       12.0  15         88  27
105140        2.0  39         53  24
```